# Django CORS requests creating 403 Forbidden Error only on server

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, django-cors-headers

I have an application which uses Django for the backend and react for the frontend so I setup django-cors-headers. When I tested the application locally with the settings I added, I had no issues. But I deployed to my server, I kept getting 403 error on API requests (except GET requests).

Below is my settings.py file (only the relevant settings):

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<my-secret-key>'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<my-server-ip>']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'frontend',
    'services',
    'rest_framework',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'user',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://<my-server-ip>:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://0.0.0.0"
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://<my-server-ip>:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://0.0.0.0"
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

I make the API requests from React using axios in the form *axios.post('http://:8000/api-endpoint', body, config)* with *then* and *catch* blocks.

The specific errors that I am getting are:

```
xhr.js:177 POST http://<my-server-ip>:8000/api/auth/login/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

and

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Comment: Looks like it's a 403 returned by your backend, nothing with CORS here

Comment: This code works completely fine locally but when migrating to my deployment server and changing the IP address the problem arose. Therefore the problem must be with CORS not my backend. 

Additionally, everytime I reset my browsers cookies, the first request works but each additional one after the creates the above error.

Comment: CORS Errors do not return any 4xx http code. So nothing related to cors here! You might have an error with your cookie for auth. Check if your front end really sends the auth credentials by inspecting network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to dbuchet, I found that the problem here was not CORS, rather the fact that in my settings.py file, I had both session and token authentication listed as the default authentication classes - removing the session authentication class fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: want to tell us how you fixed it ? add some details....